# Qt QSplitter fixed-height widget on window resize

Tags: c++, qt, qsplitter

I have a vertical `QSplitter` in the main window of my Qt desktop app with 2 widgets.

I'm trying to find a way to have it so the height of the bottom widget remains fixed when resizing the window, but can still be resized by the user when they drag the handle. I've looked, and apparently `QSplitter` isn't really meant for this and that the bottom widget should just have a resizing handle, but I'm having real issues finding documentation (with most documentation referring back to `QSplitter`); the bottom widget is a `QTabView`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it; I used `setStretchFactor` to make the top widget do all the *stretching*; consequently making the bottom widget remain at a fixed size.

```
// Widget 0 is the top widget, 100 is a stretch-factor of 100%.
mySplitView->setStretchFactor(0,100);
```

Comment: Thanks! Spent ages trying to figure this one out.

Comment: PS. You can mark your own answers correct.